# Разделение большого файла на несколько частей с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача, нужно разделить файл на несколько частей, а потом собрать его. Думал решить через преобразования любого файла в ТХТ и вытаскивать по несколько тысяч строк, но выглядит как костыль. Файлы размером от 1Мб до 15Гб. Отдельную Библиотеку писать на С# к сожалению не умею, пытаюсь выкрутиться тем что есть. Заранее спасибо!!!

```
import os
import shutil
def split_file():
    splitLen= 500
    outputBase = 'E:/codes/piligrim/rezka/data'
    fil='E:/codes/piligrim/qwe.jpeg'
    input = open(fil,'rb').read().split(b'\x11',maxsplit=-1)
    i=100
    for lines in range (0,len(input),splitLen):
        outputData = input[lines:lines+splitLen]
        output=open(outputBase+str(i)+'.txt','wb')
        print(outputData)
        if i==100:
            output.write(b'\x11'.join(outputData))
            output.close()
        else:
            output.write(b'\x11'+b'\x11'.join(outputData))
            output.close()
        i+=1
    print("операция разделение файла прошла успешна")
def merge_file():
    with open('E:/codes/piligrim/gote/qwe2.txt' , 'wb') as fdst:
        sourscepath = 'E:/codes/piligrim/rezka/'
        for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(sourscepath):
            sorted(files)
            print(files)
            for file in files:
                filename = sourscepath+file
                with open(filename,'rb') as fsrc:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc,fdst,1024*1024*10)    
    print("операция слияния файла прошла успешно")

if __name__=="__main__":
    split_file()
    merge_file()
```

Comment: "Пытаюсь выкрутиться тем что есть. Заранее спасибо" незачто )) добавьте в вопрос свои выкручивания и что с ними не так?

Comment: Так исходно файлы текстовые или нет? И в чём вообще смысл сего действа, зачем это всё? Если задача учебная - ну, думайте, как сделать. А если для дела нужно, то берёте почти любой архиватор, задаёте максимальный размер тома - и он сам поделит.

Comment: задача не учебная, это одна из функций программы так что архиватор не поможет.

Comment: @Goshan Можно архиватор в виде библиотеки подключить, если не хотите в виде отдельной программы использовать. Но в любом случае задача нуждается в уточнении: какой тип файлов изначально? почему их нужно делить - они будут передаваться через какой-то специфичный канал? тогда нужно знать ещё, какие ограничения у этого канала, чтобы правильно данные к передаче подготовить. Пока задача слишком абстрактная.

Comment: Почему бы просто не вызвать [split](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html), сформировав нужные аргументы?

Comment: Ну тогда копируйте в бинарном виде, так будет надёжнее.

Comment: @CrazyElf Файлы любые. Части которые получились не должны быть читаемы или выполнять какие либо функции. При сборке всех частей файла должен получится оригинал, который откроется при изменении расширения на изначальный. Думаю что нужно выполнить побайтовое разделение, но не понимаю как именно это сделать. Через TXT получилось разобрать файл, но вот при обратной сборке, исходный файл не получается. Возможно использую не тот encoding, может что-то другое.

Comment: @CrazyElf, только начал знакомиться с работой Python и бинарным чтением, попробую переделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, у меня получилось) вот код который делает деление файла по **ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОМУ БАЙТУ**, я взял `\x11` не знаю что он означает, но мне это не нужно главное программа работает. **Внимание** если пробуете с большими файлами то нужно увеличить количество строк в `splitLen` иначе получите тысячи файлов. В принципе если вам нужны эти тысячи файлов, то все нормально, но программа потратит больше времени на открытие каждого. напомню что нужно поменять расширение в готовом файле на исходное.

```
import shutil
def split_file():
    splitLen= 500
    outputBase = 'E:/codes/piligrim/rezka/data'
    fil='E:/codes/piligrim/qwe.jpeg'
    input = open(fil,'rb').read().split(b'\x11',maxsplit=-1)
    i=100
    for lines in range (0,len(input),splitLen):
        outputData = input[lines:lines+splitLen]
        output=open(outputBase+str(i)+'.txt','wb')
        if i==100:
            output.write(b'\x11'.join(outputData))
            output.close()
        else:
            output.write(b'\x11'+b'\x11'.join(outputData))
            output.close()
        i+=1
    print("операция разделение файла прошла успешна")
def merge_file():
    with open('E:/codes/piligrim/gote/qwe2.txt' , 'wb') as fdst:
        sourscepath = 'E:/codes/piligrim/rezka/'
        for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(sourscepath):
            sorted(files)
            print(files)
            for file in files:
                filename = sourscepath+file
                with open(filename,'rb') as fsrc:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc,fdst,1024*1024*10)    
    print("операция слияния файла прошла успешно")

if __name__=="__main__":
    split_file()
    merge_file()
```